# Automatically call a method from unknown class

Tags: java

First of all, I am new in Java and I don't know yet a lot about it I just came up with this new idea.

Let's say I have a method `methodCondition(String,String,String)` where I want to be put in any class.

The scenario of code is below:

**Where everything is started**

```
public class MainClass{

    public static void main(String... args) 
    {
        //Whe everything started, call StartFunction from proccesshelper class to Start a Thread.
        ProccessHelper phelper = new ProccessHelper();
        phelper.StartFunction();
    }

    public void methodCondition(String data1, String data2, String data3){
        //Do something about the data when this method is fire from Thread
    }
}
```

**A class where functions can call**

```
public class ProccessHelper{

    //Some function here

    public void StartFunction(){

        MyThread mythread = new MyThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(mythread);
        t.start();
    }

    //Some function here
}
```

**A thread where `methodCondition(String,String,String)`  is able to fire**

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    volatile boolean StopThread = false;
    public MyThread(){}

    public void Stop(boolean stopThread){
        this.StopThread = stopThread;
    }

    public void run(){
        if(dontLoop){
            while(true){
                if(condition = true){
                    /*
                    * if the condition here is true then call "eventMethod" from any unkown class.
                    */
                    methodCondition(String data1, String data2, String data3);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, it is possible that the `MyThread` can call `methodCondition(String,String,String)` in any class where it is register just like listening and waiting to be call?

Just like what I said, I don't know yet a lot in Java, I don't know what kind of function is this or if this is possible I just came up with this Idea. 
So if anyone can tell,explain or give a link for any reference about what I am trying to achieve that will be very appreciated. I am also open for any clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Use a listener system like Swing does.

Comment: Sounds something  like the observer pattern, There is a lot to find in the net.

Comment: People in [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) should review the purpose of [Vote Down](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am happy to found it and it is called [Invoking Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html). And to be clear, what I really want is to find for specific name of `method` from unknown class and if it is exist then call it to fire specific task.

in Addition, the code I've done is below and it's work:

```
Class c=Class.forName("MainActivity"); 
Method m=c.getMethod("methodCondition", String.class, String.class, String.class); //The method has 3 String paramaters so I have to intialize it otherwise it will produce an error that the method was not found.
Object t = c.newInstance();
m.invoke(t,"Hello Word!", "this is", "to Invoke Method"); //Now invoke the method with the value or paramaters.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call methodCondition from any class you must declare like static method. The statics methods can be called without instantiate the container class.

```
public static void methodCondition(String data1, String data2, String data3){
    //Do something about the data when this method is fire from Thread
}
```

After declare like static you can call it directly:

```
MainClass.methodCondition(...);
```

All classes must be in the same package, or import MainClass where you want to use methodCondition.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the class name, better put it in an `interface` and accept that interface as an input to your thread and call it from interface reference. This method could be inner to thread or can be a normal interface. Below is the example with inner interface.

**Thread Code:**

```
class MyThread implements Runnable {

    interface interfaceName {
        void methodName(String data1, String data2, String data3);
    }

    interfaceName interfaceReference = null;

    // Other members declaration

    private MyThread(interfaceName obj) {
        interfaceReference = obj;
    }

    public static MyThread getInstance(interfaceName obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        return new MyThread(obj);
    }

    public void run() {
        // Do your stuff
        interfaceReference.methodName("", "", "");
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

**Other Classes Example:**

```
public class Temp implements MyThread.interfaceName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Temp t = new Temp();
        MyThread mt = MyThread.getInstance(t);
    }

    public void methodName(String data1, String data2, String data3) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```